# Appium: Unable to launch the application in real device

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, eclipse-plugin, appium

I'm new to Appium. I have installed all the pre-requisite and run the script in eclipse but i got the below error in console. Please help me.

Script:
public void testSample() throws MalformedURLException{

```
    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.VERSION,"4.0.4");
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,"YT9100LVGT");
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE, "com.android.calculator2");
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY, "com.android.calculator2.Calculator");

    AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),cap);
```

Error in console: 
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: 'java -version' failed. Error: Command failed: Error: opening registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'
Error: could not find java.dll
Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.
) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 1.02 seconds
Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:03:00'
System info: host: 'LENOVO-PC', ip: '175.16.1.122', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_65'

Error log in Appium server:
 info: Client User-Agent string: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.4 (java 1.5)

> info: [debug] The following desired capabilities were provided, but not recognized by appium. They will be passed on to any other services running on this server. : version
>   info: [debug] Didn't get app but did get Android package, will attempt to launch it on the device
>   info: [debug] Creating new appium session e6da8fb1-3097-4b47-9e32-ac5f38129755
>   info: Starting android appium
>   info: [debug] Getting Java version
>   info: [debug] Cleaning up android objects
>   error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: 'java -version' failed. Error: Command failed: Error: opening registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'
>   Error: could not find java.dll
>   Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.
>
> info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session
>   info: [debug] Error: 'java -version' failed. Error: Command failed: Error: opening registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'
>   Error: could not find java.dll
>   Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.
>
> ```
> at C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Mobile automation\AppiumForWindows-1.3.4.1\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\devices\android\android-common.js:1033:17
> at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:641:7)
> at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
> at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
> at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:956:11)
> at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
> at Pipe.close (net.js:465:12)
> ```
>
> info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: 'java -version' failed. Error: Command failed: Error: opening registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'\r\nError: could not find java.dll\r\nError: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.\r\n)","origValue":"'java -version' failed. Error: Command failed: Error: opening registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'\r\nError: could not find java.dll\r\nError: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.\r\n"},"sessionId":null}
>   info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 567.298 ms - 548

Comment: Check if you have set JAVA_HOME properly

Answer (score 0):

SET java_home in environment variables

Answer (score 0):

Finally after research, I got solution for the issue. Uninstall the java in control panel and delete java related files in system32 and syswow64. Reinstall the java new version.